# Scroll to an md-list-item in md-list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have following code in angular, displaying a list with user content.

```
<md-list flex>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" data-ng-class="{'item-selected-background': item.id === selectedItem.id}"
              aria-label="Item" ng-click="onClickItem(item, $event)" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
        <h5>Name: {{item.name}}</h5>
        <h6>Address: {{item.address}}</h6>
        <h6>City: {{item.city}}</h6>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

This list is huge and has hundreds of items. If *selectedItem* changes in controller then that md-list-item should get highlighted and list should automatically scroll to that item in UI.

I could not find a solution to this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [angular-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-scroll).
To manage your scroll, you need to measure container height of your `md-list`. In my case I will use `div` with `ng-repeat`

You can write directive that will find item to scroll to as:

```
app.directive('scrollToNoteIf', ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {

    var getScrollingParent = function(element, _parent) {

        var container = _parent;

        var container = angular.element(document.getElementById(container));
        var section2 = angular.element(document.getElementById(element.id));


        if(!container || !section2){
            return;
        }


        $timeout(function () {
            container.scrollTo(section2, 40, 0);
        }, 200);


    };
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.scrollToNoteIf, function(value) {
            if (value) {
                getScrollingParent(element[0], attrs.scrollToNoteIdContainer);        
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

So the usage will look like:

```
<md-content>
  <div  id="some-container-id">
     <div  ng-repeat="obj in vm.activity.objectives"
           id="id_{{obj.id}}"
           scroll-to-note-if="obj.id === $root.selected_id"
           scroll-to-note-id-container="some-container-id">      

        <wm-item objective="obj">
        </wm-item>
     </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

By replacing `obj.id === $root.selected_id` with your own you will be able to scroll to any item you want

---

I think this example will help you to sort things out.